# ethers.js swapExactTokensForTokens not happening (no errors)

Tags: tokens, javascript, ethers.js, nodejs, router

Been stuck on swapping tokens using ethers js, here's the code I'm using:

```
const https_provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(https_provider_addres)
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic)
const account = wallet.connect(provider)
const https_account = wallet.connect(https_provider)

const erc20_ABI =
    [
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "name",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_spender",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "approve",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "totalSupply",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_from",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "transferFrom",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "decimals",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint8"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_owner",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "balanceOf",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "balance",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "symbol",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "transfer",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_owner",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_spender",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "allowance",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "payable": true,
            "stateMutability": "payable",
            "type": "fallback"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "owner",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "spender",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Approval",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "from",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Transfer",
            "type": "event"
        }
    ]

const addresses = {
    WAVAX: "0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7",
    router: "0x60aE616a2155Ee3d9A68541Ba4544862310933d4",
    factory: "0x9Ad6C38BE94206cA50bb0d90783181662f0Cfa10",
}

const router = new ethers.Contract(
    addresses.router,
    [
        'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
        'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
        'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    ],
    account
)

const USDC_address = '0xB97EF9Ef8734C71904D8002F8b6Bc66Dd9c48a6E'

const STG_address = "0x2F6F07CDcf3588944Bf4C42aC74ff24bF56e7590"
const STG_contract = new ethers.Contract(
    STG_address,
    erc20_ABI,
    https_account
)

const swap = async () => {

    console.log('swap starting')

    const amountIn = "22146823544065952776"

    const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [
        STG_address,
        USDC_address
    ])

    const amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(12))
    console.log('amountOutMin: ' + amountOutMin)

    const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        [STG_address, USDC_address],
        https_account.address,
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 6, // 6 mins from current
        {
            gasLimit: 5000009999
        }
    )

    console.log('Swap done!')
    const receipt = await tx.wait()
    console.log('Transaction receipt' + receipt)
}

const init = async () => {
    console.log('before contract approve')

    //
    let receipt = STG_contract.connect(https_account).approve("0x60aE616a2155Ee3d9A68541Ba4544862310933d4", ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000.0', 18)).then((results) => {
        console.log(results)
        swap()
    })

    console.log(receipt)
    console.log('await contract approve happened')
}

init()
```

The approve works fine, I get the expected console output, tx hash (can verify on snowtrace etc)

Problem is with the actual swap, I get the amounts out, but after when attempting swapExactTokensForTokens basically nothing happens - it just keeps hanging forever, no errors, nothing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First I would do try using a single provider. Now you have `provider` and `https_provider`, which I guess are different? It's possible that `provider` isn't working so I would change the following:

```js
//const account = wallet.connect(provider)
const account = wallet.connect(https_provider)
```

Also I would try the following, waiting for the approve receipt before swapping:

```js
const init = async () => {
    console.log('before contract approve')

    // let's complete the approve first
    let tx_receipt = await STG_contract.connect(https_account).approve("0x60aE616a2155Ee3d9A68541Ba4544862310933d4", ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000.0', 18));
    let receipt = await tx_receipt.wait();
    console.log(receipt)

    // onto the swap
    await swap()
}
```

If the above two solutions don't work, I guess it's a nonce problem. It's possible that by sending two txs in a short time the provider used the same nonce in both, so the second one was dropped. To fix this you need to get the nonce of the account, and specifically use `nonce` in approve and `nonce+1` in swap.

```js
const nonce = await account.getTransactionCount();

let tx_receipt = await STG_contract.connect(account).approve(
    "0x60aE616a2155Ee3d9A68541Ba4544862310933d4",
    ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000.0', 18),
    {
        nonce: nonce,
    }
);

// ...

const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    [STG_address, USDC_address],
    https_account.address,
    Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 6, // 6 mins from current
    {
        nonce: nonce+1,
        gasLimit: 5000009999
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah the provider was unnecessary, just the https one is in use

I managed to move a few swaps through, but also got a few 'nonce too low' errors - how to best set custom nonce? Can you get a total tx count via ethers js and then +1 etc?

Comment: @soundcake Yeah, with `account.getTransactionCount()`. I added some lines to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, 

Nice one:) This does help, I do need to figure out a way of reliably performing a bunch of transactions consecutively (it'll be automated eventually). Currently still running into gas / nonce issues, but this is helpful indeed

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with a huge `gasLimit` number on avalanche, as in my experience it causes an extra gas fee. First, try to change it to at least `1_000_000`. Ideally, estimate it via `await router.estimateGas['swapExactTokensForTokens'](...params)`.

I also agree with [0xSanson's reply](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/136193/109086) - you have to await for tx to be confirmed. In your case, you're using a callback to await tx to be signed, and not confirmed.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get a few swaps happen by retrying and also tweaking around the gas settings - since I want this automated I need to find a reliable method that wouldn't rely on me retrying etc so that estimateGas could be the answer

So sometimes it works, sometimes I'm getting gas / nonce errors basically at the moment